# App inventor 2 App: RowID Fusion Table

Tags: mysql, app-inventor

With App inventor 2 I got the ROWID number and I put the value in the "riga" variable. The Query is executing once and it writes correctely the data in the fusion table row, but then the query keeps on executing many times and the app writes hundred of times "400 Bad Request: Rowid must contains only numerals and underscores".
Why is it happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you created an endless loop

you should add a variable let's name it action, set it to *rowid* while you get the rowid and set it to *update* while you do the update

in the `fusiontable controls got result` event you need an if statement like this (pseudocode)

```
if action = "rowid"
then extract the received rowid and do the update
else print "update was successful"
```

btw. to get the rowid, you better [split](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/text.html#split) the result at **\n** (new line) to convert it into a list with 2 items, then select the second item to get the row id